# php.ini path inside code

Tags: path, php

To get php.ini path i simply run

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

what is the way to get the php.ini path to show to the user. without showing the whole phpinfo file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have PHP 5.2.4 or later, you can simply use the [php_ini_loaded_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php) method which returns the path as a string.

If you don't have that version, here's one way.

```
ob_start();
phpinfo(INFO_GENERAL);
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$lines = explode("\n", $data);
foreach($lines as $line){
    list($name, $value) = explode("=>", $line);
    if (trim($name) == 'Loaded Configuration File') break;
}    
echo $name . ' - ' . $value."\n";
```

That simply prints:

> Loaded Configuration File  -
> /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

Of course you could use a regex match or something fancier like that if you wanted to.

Answer (score 3):

`phpinfo(INFO_GENERAL)` would be smaller

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: not what i wanted.. i want to use the path value for php.ini inside my script.